# Argument of type '{ value: BigNumber; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Overrides & { from?: string | Promise<string> | undefined; }'

Tags: typescript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am developing a smart contract with solidity(version 0.8.0) at buildspace here is my code snippet in TypeScript(4.5.x)/JavaScript, and node 16.13.x

```js
...
const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy({
    value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
});

...
```

The above code is written in a file called: `run.ts` To execute the code, this is the command:
`npx hardhat run scripts/run.ts`

Here is the head of the error I got with its tail truncated:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ value: BigNumber; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Overrides & { from?: string | Promise<string> | undefined; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'Overrides & { from?: string | Promise<string> | undefined; }'.

7     value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
....
```

with "7" above showing the line where the error occurred.

I didn't know where the error is coming from. The code keeps failing for `run.ts/js`

I am trying to fund my smart contract with 0.1 ether.

Here is the snippet to my smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal {
...
 constructor() {
    console.log("Hello, Multiverse... I am Smart Contract WavePortal");
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So after making research for some hours, I found the answer [here](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2021/08/remix-ide-deploy-causing-failed-deployed-contract-transaction-with-value/).

I had to add a `payable` modifier to the contract's constructor and it work:

```
contract WavePortal {
...
 constructor() payable {
    console.log("Hello, Multiverse... I am Smart Contract WavePortal");
  }
...
}
```